# Sum Bigdecimals inside Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I´m using Java 8 Stream where I iterate over two collections, and after pass a filter I want to sum one of the bigdecimal variables that I have inside my stream to an external bigDecimal variable "restrictionsNumber"

Here my code:

```
     final BigDecimal restrictionsNumber = cmd.amount.getNumberOfUnits();
        order.products()
             .stream()
             .flatMap(product -> product.getRestrictions()
                                    .stream()
                                    .filter(restriction -> restriction.equals(newProductRestriction))
                                    .map(restriction -> restrictionsNumber.add(product.getAmount()
                                                                            .getNumberOfUnits())));
```

The last map is the one where I´m trying to sum the two bigdecimals. 
I know I´m doing something wrong. 
Can anyone give me an advise about how to do it with Stream.

I´m trying to refactor from this old fashion code

```
 final BigDecimal restrictionsNumber = cmd.amount.getNumberOfUnits();
 for (Product product : order.products()) {
     for (String oldProductRestriction : product.getRestrictions()) {
         if (oldProductRestriction.equals(newProductRestriction)) {
            restrictionsNumber = restrictionsNumber.add(product.getAmount()
                                                                       .getNumberOfUnits());
          }
      }
  }
```

Regards.

Comment: I still do not understand on what you are trying to do. You want to have sum of all big integers?

Comment: Only those that pass this filter ".filter(restriction -> restriction.equals(newProductRestriction))"

Comment: This is unclear. Can you post a sample input / output and explain what you want to do?

Comment: take a look if is more clear now the description

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be what you need (but it keeps adding the same amount several times for each product, in line with your original code, which seems weird):

```
BigDecimal sum = order.products()
     .stream()
     .flatMap(product -> product.getRestrictions()
                  .stream()
                  .filter(restriction -> restriction.equals(newProductRestriction))
                  .map(restriction -> product.getAmount().getNumberOfUnits()))
     .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
BigDecimal result = restrictionsNumber.add(sum);
```

Comment: Yes, you use the reduce just as I need. I was trying to do the add inside the stream, but I guess is not possible or is wrong.Thanks for your code

Comment: If that’s really the intended operation, counting the number of matching items, followed by a multiplication, using `map` instead of `flatMap` would simplify it.

Comment: @Holger Yes - definitely.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the "[reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html)" operation.
Reduce is used for operations like summing over a whole stream, or adding finding the maximum.

(If you want your addition to happen for a single stream element then your question was unclear to me, please add detail)

Comment: I consider the reduce, but what I want is to sum a value of my stream with an external variable.      final BigDecimal restrictionsNumber = cmd.amount.getNumberOfUnits();